# ObjectInputStream throws ioexception inside the filelock lock section

Tags: java, multithreading, nio, filechannel, filelock

I have a function, that has to put key value pair into map stored in file. If file does not exist, I have to create it. I try to lock the file, when I work with it with Filelock lock(). But when I try to write into it( Inside of the locked section), I get IO exception: 
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file
I, probably, don't use the lock() right. Here is my function:

```
        private void createDataSet(String key, String data) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

                final   String path = (fileName);
    //            1. Check if file exists
    //            2. If file exists, write/override key/value.
                Path nPath = Paths.get(path);
                HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    //            createFile is atomic, no need to check if exists.
                    try(FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(nPath,StandardOpenOption.WRITE,StandardOpenOption.APPEND
                            , StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
                        FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(path, false);
                        ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

                        ){
                        FileLock lock = fileChannel.lock();
                        if(fileChannel.size()==4){
                            map.put(key, values);
                            oos.writeObject(map);
                        }else{
                            ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(fileChannel));
                            Object obj = objectIn.readObject();
                            map = (HashMap<String, List<String>>) obj;
                            map.put(key, values);
// In this row exception being throwed:
                            oos.writeObject(map); 
                        }
                        oos.close();
                        fos.close();
                        lock.release();
                    }
                    return;
```

Comment: Would be happy to hear about any other solution for creating file/opening existing file with lock, to make the write operation thread safe.

Comment: Throws what `IOException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open the file twice - once via `FileChannel`, another via `FileOutputStream`. You then lock the file via `FileChannel` but try to write to it via `FileOutputStream`. That's why the stream is blocked by the lock by the channel.

`FileChannel` has its own read/write methods. Use either channel or stream, but not both.

[Edit] the file lock is to prevent another process from writing to it, so unless you know there is some other process that might try to write to your file, there is generally no need to explicitly lock a file before writing to it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, would update soon! Regarding Lock: I use it, since the file might be open by other thread( of the same program). If i understand right, it's better solution, than synchronized on file path, for example.